# Can I extract C++ template arguments out of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Basically, given a template class like this:

```
template< class Value > class Holder { };
```

I would like to be able to discover the type `Value` for a given `Holder` class. I thought that I would be able to make a simple metafunction that takes a template template argument, like this:

```
template< template< class Value > class Holder > class GetValue
{
    typedef Value Value;
};
```

And then extract out the `Value` type like this:

```
GetValue< Holder< int > >::Value value;
```

But instead I just get an error message pointing to the metafunction declaration:

```
error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
```

Is there any way to accomplish this kind of thing? Thanks.

[EDIT] I also get the error messages:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class Value> class Holder> class GetValue’
error:   expected a class template, got ‘Holder<int>’
```

Which leads me to conclude that Phil Nash is right, you can't pass a class as a template template argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you simply change your holder class to

```
template< class Value > class Holder {
    typedef Value value_type;

    value_type m_val; // member variable
};
```

In any method that consumes an object of type Holder< T > you can access the contained type like that:

```
template< class THolder >
void SomeMethod( THolder const& holder ) {
     typename THolder::value_type v = holder.m_val;
}
```

This approach follows the pattern all STL classes use, e.g., std::vector< int >::value_type is int.

I think you're trying to do partial template specialization:

```
template<class T>
class GetValue {
};

template<class Value>
class GetValue< Holder<Value> > {
public:
    typedef Value value_type;
};
```

In your code, you could then do the following:

```
template<class THolder>
void SomeMethod( THolder const& h ) {
    typename GetValue< THolder >::value_type v = h.m_v;
}
```

In general, I'd prefer the first solution though.

Comment: It's not always possible to do this. I've certainly needed the externalised form before

Comment: I've added an external form using partial template specialization.

Comment: You're right of course. You can use the external form in boost style to define e.g. the value_type of an array using the same partial specialization approach.

Comment: the partial template specialization would be the right approach for me. thanks!

Comment: @drpepper: That's how metaprogramming in C++ is. With the partial specialization it should also be possible to make it even more generic (as in your example): `template <class T, template <class> class Holder> struct GetType<Holder<T> >{ typedef T type; };`

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T> void extract_type(Holder<T>)
{
    printf("%s\n", typeid(T).name());
}
```

I'm assuming though that you want to use that in a non-templated function. That's a bit more difficult:

```
template <class T> class GetValue;
template <class T> class GetValue<Holder<T> >
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

The magic google words are "partial template specialization"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a typename in there somewhere.

[edit]
Damn, was just going to check my suspicion that it needed to be before the GetValue, but Mykola got there first :-)

The issue is that Value is a dependent type. The compiler doesn't know whether it is meant to name a type or a value, so you need to provide the hint.

[edit2]

Oops. There is a problem with trying to answer too fast.
I missed the fact that you were trying to use a template template to achieve this.
What that allows you to do is to pass a *template* in instead of a *type*. In this case you can pass a Holder. But that doesn't help you because you want to pass a type, Holder<int>.

Looks like Mykola realised this too and removed his answer.

You'll need to use Partial Template Specialization for this. Before I had a chance to complete my own example Sebastian has beaten me to it :-)

Comment: you guys are too fast! i can't afford to make any typos here ;)

but the typo is not the real problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you update your original question to reflect your change to make sure we're on the same page?

Comment: I think you are right, missing typename seems to be the issue. @drepper: If not, then post the updated code.

Comment: @naveen I added a typedef but it didn't make a difference

Comment: @drpepper typename, you mean? - in any case the real problem was the template template