# Is it possible to check at compile time whether a type is derived from some instantiation of a template?

Tags: c++, inheritance, metaprogramming

I would like to write a template function which behaves one way if the passed type is derived from any template instantiation of another class, and another way if not.

I think the code below captures what I would like to do. Unfortunately Caller prints "generic" for both `double` and `Derived`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived
:
    public Base<int>
{
};

template <typename T>
void Foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(const Base<T>&)
{
    std::cout << "derives from Base<T>" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Caller(const T& t)
{
    Foo(t);
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    Caller(x);

    Derived d;
    Caller(d);

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that Caller doesn't know which instantiation of `Base` that its parameter might derive from.)

Answer (score 2):

It's calling the `const T&` overload because its a better match than `const base<T>&`. The reason is because calling the first requires no conversions and the second requires a derived-to-base conversion.

Here's a quick hack that shows you how it can be done (note the introduced base class):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct EvenMoreBase {};

template <typename T>
struct Base : EvenMoreBase
{
};

struct Derived
:
    public Base<int>
{
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<EvenMoreBase, T>::value>::type
Foo(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(const Base<T>&)
{
    std::cout << "derives from Base<T>" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void Caller(const T& t)
{
    Foo(t);
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    Caller(x);

    Derived d;
    Caller(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The introduced base class is convenient, however I would venture it is unnecessary. After all, if `Foo(Base<T> const&)` manages to deduce a `T` that works, one could write a specialized predicate class that does the same.

Comment: @MatthieuM: That's what I really want to know, but I'm not sure whether it's possible. Is it possible to write a helper which gives you `int` when you pass it `Derived`?

Comment: @Mozza314: But that's not at all your original question, is it? If you want to know the `T` is used in instantiation of `Base<T>`, you don't need neither argument deduction, nor any fany meta-programming. simply put a `typedef T base_type` there, as suggested in my answer. For any concrete class `Derived` that derives from some `Base<T>`, `Derived::base_type` is already known. Or is the problem, that you want to extract the type of something of which you don't know if it's a class template? Little confused here.

Comment: @thokra: True, it wasn't my original question, but I figure that's what I need for my original question, or at least, that's one solution that would work. Having the base_type typedef kinda works, actually it's currently my preferred solution, but it requires modifying the base class. I'd like to know if, in more general terms, it is possible to determine whether you are derived from a given template.

Comment: @Mozza314: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764680/can-i-extract-c-template-arguments-out-of-a-template-class

Comment: @MatthieuM.: How could you do this? You'd be limited to derived types of the form `T : Base<T>`, wouldn't you? If so, that's trivial to find out.

Comment: @thokra: you would not, one solution is the method you exposed (you had my +1, btw, simple and works), another would be using overload resolution (after all when calling `Foo(Base<T> const&)` the compiler manages to deduce `T`) however leveraging overload resolution to build a trait is a bit of tricky.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well thanks. :D "however leveraging overload resolution to build a trait is a bit of tricky" - if it's a viable solution here, could you draw it up? I'd be very interested as well. I banged my head on the table this morning trying to figure it out. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use C++11 (or `<type_traits>` in general), the following is also a possible solution and covers not only types `T : Base<T>`, i.e. instances of the CRTP, but also `T : Base<U>` without another base class, as requested in your example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
  typedef T base_value_type;
};

struct Derived : public Base<int>
{
};

template <typename T, typename = T>
struct IsDerived
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct IsDerived<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base<typename T::base_value_type>, T>::value, T>::type>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};


template <typename T>
void Caller(const T&)
{
  std::cout << IsDerived<T>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Caller(double());  // false
  Caller(Derived()); // true

  return 0;
}
```

Note the `typedef T base_value_type` - which might be called whatever your like. The idea is that each type `T` derived from `Base<U>` can leverage the knowledge of the base's template parameter. It doesn't matter if `T == U` or not. Trying to substitute the second parameter will fail as soon as you pass in a `T` that has no `typedef T base_value_type` and thus no specialization for this particular `T` will be generated.

**EDIT**: After processing your comment, and inspired by the thread I posted, I tried to somehow extract some base parameter `U` when examining some time type `T : Base<U>`. I don't think this can be done in the way you want, i.e. you pass whatever `T` and you extract `U`. However, you can do two things.

**Simple Solution:** If you have control over how derived classes are implemented, instead of adding a `typedef` in the base class, simply add a corresponding typedef in the derived class:

```
template <typename BaseParamType>
class Derived : public Base<BaseParamType>
{
public:
  typedef BaseParamType base_param_type;
}
```

or, if you don't want derived classes to be class templates as well, simply hard code the type right into the type (you already know the type of the base parameter):

```
class Derived : public Base<int>
{
public:
  typedef int base_param_type;
}
```

**More involved solution**: What you can do, at least for an *expected subset* of possible `U`s, is the following:

```
template <typename DerivedType,
          typename BaseParamType = DerivedType,
          bool   = std::is_base_of<Base<BaseParamType>, DerivedType>::value>
struct Extract
{
  typedef BaseParamType type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Extract<T, U, false>;

int main()
{
  Extract<DerivedCRTP>::type;     // CRTP - trivial
  Extract<Derived, int>::type;    // type == int, Derived is derived from Base<int>
  Extract<Derived, double>::type; // compile-time error, undefined template

  return 0;
}
```

This isn't as convenient as passing some instance of a type to a deducing template function and have it magically , but you can at least test if some type `T` derives from `Base<U>` and get a compile-time error if it doesn't.

Comment: Actually, the `IsDerived` structure is not important for the original problem (specializing `Foo`), and if you rewrite your question with `Foo` instead of `IsDerived`, you get a C++03 conforming answer to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Since the base class has to be a concrete class (not a template), it is not possible to know whether it is a template or a non-template class.

In another words :

```
struct A1 : public B1
{};

struct A2 : public B2<int>
{};
```

in both of these cases both base classes are concrete types.